# Single word for "inguinal crease"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for "inguinal crease"?

In order of preference (most preferable at the top):

- everyday English name
- medical term
- nickname
- slang

Anyway it should be a single word.

Thanks.

P.S.: I am also ready to surrender to the fact that there is no such word.

Comment: It is not clear what you are talking about, [crease](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/crease) has multiple meanings. Write a sentence to explain the context in which it will be used.

Comment: I suggest you try some bodybuilder site. They're the folks who are interested in such things.

Comment: @Yohann, the inguinal crease is the diagonal crease between the pelvis and the thigh.

Comment: Urban Dictionary gives a couple of synonyms.  However I don't think there is a *single* word answer in any of the categories you specify.

Answer (score 2):

[Basic search](https://www.google.de/search?q=inguinal%20crease%20names&oq=inguinal%20crease%20names&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30.24559.28044.0.28243.8.4.1.3.4.0.134.397.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.8.404.ubQtRwcEhE4) gives :

- [second result](http://www.menshealth.com/fitness/inguinal-crease) :

> It goes by many names: love line, **moneymaker**, Marky's mark, the Michelangelo muscle.

- [third result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groin) is a wikipedia article about Groin where you can find an explanation that leads to [pectineus muscle article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectineus_muscle) where there is a good schema about the zone. According to the schema, what you are looking for may be called [Iliacus muscle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliacus_muscle).
- [fourth result](http://featpersonaltraining.blogspot.de/2013/08/inguinal-crease.html) :

> It goes by many names (Love-Line, Marky's Mark, Adonis Muscle...)

Comment: Thanks Yohann. However, I would say the Iliacus muscle is something related but different. Pity "moneymaker" is a very generic term.